# How do to hibernate OS X in order to reboot to Windows 10

Tags: macos, windows, dual-boot, hibernate

I have Yosemite and Windows 10 installed on my Macbook Pro 2015.
On Windows 10 I can hibernate. Then press the power button and hold down ALT key to boot from OS X.
However, I can't do the same thing the other way around.
I have to shut down Yosemite or restart, in order for the ALT key to work for booting options.

I tried the pmset hibernationmode 25 thingy with 1 second of standbydelay - when I press the sleep button and after that the power button, holding down ALT key doesn't give OS boot option menu.

Is there a way to achieve with OS X what Windows does?

I am trying to find a working way to do that for a few days now, browsing a bunch of topics here on stackexchange and different articles over the internet - nothing seems to work.
I haven't tried third party paid applications though.
Tried DeepSleep application - it's hibernation feature also doesn't bring up the boot menu when holding down ALT either. I am not even sure if it even hibernates.

Comment: have you found any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Nope. OS X only has sleep, no hibernate mode. If you want to save your work while dual-booting, try a virtual machine, like Parallels or VMWare Fusion.

Comment: This would seem to claim otherwise - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51726/85275

Comment: OS X indeed does have hibernate mode. By default, on a laptop, it uses both modes simultaneously to get the best of both worlds. Really, there's no reason to make your Mac go into hibernation mode most of the time, because of this.

Comment: Guys, seriously.
Instead of attacking this guy that obviously is wrong, try to help me.
Changing the hibernation mode to 1, 3 or 25 didn't help. I still don't have access to the boot menu where I can choose what to be booted - OS X or Windows.

Comment: @user166663 Correct. OS X has a hibernate-like mode, where it'll save memory contents to the HD, but you still cannot reboot and have access to the startup disk chooser.

Comment: @user166663 First of all, we're not attacking this guy, just correcting. Second of all, if we knew an answer to your problem, we'd contribute it! To my knowledge, there is no way to do what you want to do.

Comment: @IronCraftMan it isn't a hibernate-like mode, it is a hibernate mode. It does what hibernation is supposed to do, it just doesn't let you switch to a different OS when in that mode. That's an implementation detail, purely.